# Shiny App Isn't Finding Data in Directory on Server?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm working on posting a `Shiny` App on my own instance of a shiny server on the web.

Everything works fine, when I publish the app to shinyapps.io:
https://petemiksza.shinyapps.io/Secondary_Music_Teachers/

However, I'm not able to get the app to run on my own server.

I do have the `app.R` as well as the datafile this app uses saved into the app's directory on my server:

```
srv/shinyserver/app_folder/secondary_US_music_teacher_data
```

I also have made sure the packages are all installed in `R` on the server.

The first blocks of code in my `app.R` file deals with loading libraries and loading the data file the app uses.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(foreign)
library(survey)

# Read in data
secon_dat <- read.spss("FRSS 103 Secondary Teachers Data for App.sav", 
                   use.value.labels = TRUE, use.missings = TRUE,
                   to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

This is followed by the `ui` and `server` and the `shinyapp()` function.

Also, I have several other apps posted to my server and do not believe there is a file transfer issue or anything of that sort. However, none of my other existing apps use a data file I provide as this problematic one does.

Any troubleshooting help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a file name that does not contain spaces ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the file to `FRSS_103_Secondary_Teachers_Data_for_App.sav` and adjusted the code in the `app.R` file accordingly and that did not change the situation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the installation of the `tidyverse` package didn't take. I simply changed the libraries called in the app to the following and it now works:

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinythemes)
 library(tidyr)
 library(dplyr
 library(foreign)
 library(survey)
```